# CakeEmail with debug level 0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send an email through CakeEmail, it all works when having a debug level of 2 but as soon as I switch it to debug level 0 it stops working and I get a server error when accessing the page. I checked the logs and this is what I get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function subject() on a non-object`

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->template('forgot_password', 'default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->viewVars(array('password' => $password))
    ->from(array('my@email.com' => 'My Company'))
    ->to('my@email.com')
    ->subject('Your new password')
    ->send();
```

I've used similar code before, but can't remember if I had tried it with a debug level of 0.

Thanks,

Comment: try it without chaining `viewVars` and `emailFormat` - the manual doesn't *specifically* say those methods are chainable. Just a suggestion however

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the uses clause in the controller:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Also, make certain you are selecting the config in one of two ways:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config('default');

//or in constructor::
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
```